# Using Open MPI and CUDA in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cuda, mpi, gpgpu, openmpi

I am trying to run a Simple **CUDA** program which queries the numbers of GPUs in the nodes using **Open MPI v1.6.1** (64 bit) in **Windows 7 Professional 64** bit Machines. When I run the application in root node, the correct GPU count is getting. But when the same application is tried to run in different nodes remotely using Open MPI, the GPU count is getting as 0, ie, it is showing as **No CUDA capable GPU is present** in the node.

The root and the nodes having CUDA 2.1 capable GPUs. When a normal MPI application is running, it is working correctly.

> Is there any special settings required for running a CUDA application
>   in Windows 7 using Open MPI v1.6.1?

Comment: Can you run any CUDA application (even from SDK) under remote desktop access? As far as I remember, remote desktop in Windows provides virtual GPU and your real GPU is not accessible remotely normally.

Comment: No Windows does not allow the CUDA application to run remote desktop. But we can run the application through VNC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Windows, display GPUs are required to use Microsoft's [WDDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Display_Driver_Model) driver model. When running remote tasks on a Windows machine (e.g. via RDP or MPI) you are running in a [restricted session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx) which has a virtual display driver, as such the WDDM devices are not accessible and hence there is no GPU (i.e. no CUDA GPU).

NVIDIA's [TCC](http://www.nvidia.com/object/software-for-tesla-products.html) driver model takes the GPU out of the WDDM environment and makes it appear as a non-display device, which means it is available for CUDA work via RDP and MPI. Of course this also makes it unavailable for display.

TCC is supported on all Tesla and some Quadro devices.

Comment: The simplest solution for GeForce Windows users with this problem is a bunch of DVDs or USB sticks containing a live Linux distribution.